# Project Server PWA "Sorry, we were unable to open your project. Please try again. If this happens again, contact your administrator"

Tags: progressive-web-apps

We have Project Web App configured for our Enterprise Project Management portal which uses Microsoft Project Professional 2016 to open schedules of the projects hosted on PWA.

We use Google Chrome to access our PWA portal and open project schedules in MS Project 2016 and the entire flow was working fine till last month or so. Now, we could not open schedules in MSP 2016 through PWA as MSP fails with error "Sorry, we were unable to open your project. Please try again. If this happens again, contact your administrator"!!

Please suggest the solution for the same. One thing we observed was the process is still working in older version of Google Chrome (51.*), where as failing with mentioned error in latest versions(65.*, 68.*)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, Check this **[MS Project 2013 / 2016: Sorry, we were unable to open your project. Please try again. if this happens again, contact your administrator](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sorry-we-were-unable-to-open-your-project-please-try-again-if-this-happens-again-contact-your-administrator/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution by Martin Kotrc for this [issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a8d6f9a-8d44-4d29-9166-4643f5ad3c38/ms-project-2016-sorry-we-were-unable-to-open-your-project?forum=projectonline) using Windows 10 with MS Engineer.

> First you need to get latest version of ***MS Project - version 1803***
>   (`Build 9126.2072 Click-To-Run`)(Monthly Channel) and latest version of
>   `chrome: 65.0.3325.162`.
>
> After that
>
> **Step 1** - Remove the user account from MS Project Professional profile
>
> MS Project -> upper right corner Switch Account – Sign out all and
>   confirm.
>
> **Step 2** - Remove connected services from your Office 2016 profile
>
> File -> Account -> Connected Services -> remove all
>
> **Step 3** - Fully clear the MS Project cache
>
> `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MS` Project Delete
>   everything in folder \MS Project
>
> **Step 4** - Clear cached credentials on
>   the computer
>
> a) Edit the registry to remove cached credentials. To do this, follow
>   these steps:
>
> Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK. In Registry
>   Editor, locate the following registry subkey:
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16\Common\Identity\Identities`
>   Select the Office account that you want to get rid-off, and then
>   rename to xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx.OLD.
>
> b) Remove the cached credentials in Credentials Manager. To do this,
>   follow these steps:
>
> Open Control Panel, and then click Credentials Manager. Under Generic
>   Credentials, remove all MicrosoftOffice16_Data:ADALxxxxxxxxxx entries.
>
> c)Log off, and then log on to your computer.

Comment: Jess, thanks for the answer.. We have MS Project Professional 2016 DVD installer, not Office 365 Click to Run.. Will the process be same in that case too?

Comment: Did not work. Only common thing I observed was MS Project Cache folder which I deleted before logging out user but no luck as such.. Looks like this solution works only for Office 365 setup/environment.